# Method that fails loudly vs silently

Tags: exception, api-design

I have a method (or function, or procedure, it doesn't matter for the sake of this question) `void DoStuff()`. It has depends on some data and has side effects. Also, it is only valid to do this operation in a certain state; in certain other state this operation can not be performed.

Now, although I'm developing this as an API, I'm thinking about where this API will actually be used. There are two typical situations where this operation is performed:

1. User code should've checked, if the state is valid, and implement a custom logic of it's own if it's not. If this code ends up trying to implement this operation in invalid state it means that it's a programmer error, and it should be reported and investigated.
2. The client doesn't really need to do any custom logic in this case, and doesn't even need to know if the operation was successful or not.

To make my API useful in both situations, I want to expose two variants of this method: one `DoStuff()` that will throw exception — or, let's say, use given language's capabilities to report an error as loudly as possible to signify a logic error. And the other, `TryDoStuff()`, that will not do any error reporting at all, and will fail silently.

So, I have two questions:

1. Does it sound as a good idea to create two API endpoints instead of one? I see it as a convenience, although in general, more API endpoints mean more code to support and a more complicated API.
2. What would be an appropriate naming convention to use? Does `TryDoStuff()` work?

(This language has nothing to do with any language in particular. I use C# syntax for examples, but this question is not about C# and not even about OOP, so please don't add these tags).

Comment: Can you add a concrete example of what kind of operation you have in mind for dostuff?

Comment: I'm not sure, but this might be a question more suitable for Programmers SE (?)

Comment: And while it is true there is a language-agnostic angle to this, it should not be disregarded that there might also be language/framework-specific conventions playing into this. For instance, `Try...()` methods imply a certain fixed pattern of operation to .NET developers that might not be known under the same name on other platforms.

Comment: `public void DoStuff(bool throwOnFailure = true)`

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved in numerous ways:

- Return the result of the operation, throw upon failure.
- Return the result of the operation or a default value upon failure.
- Return the result of the operation or an error indicator upon failure.
- Return a complex result object one of whose states can express a failure.

Now, these designs are not mutually exclusive; just like `Parse`/`TryParse` methods often come in pairs in .NET, you might want to offer a "safeguarded" and a loudly failing variant of each method. More precisely, the following three ways of handling this seem viable:

- Provide two variants of each method, as described above.
- Provide several API objects from which the methods can be accessed, a "safeguarded" one and a loudly failing one.
- Provide a global API mode setting that controls the general behaviour of all methods.

Now, especially options 2 and 3 do not necessarily mean the full double amount of code to maintain. Externally, you could be able to have all API objects implement the same common interface. And internally, both options 2 and 3 (and actually, also option 1) would allow you to write the crucial internal methods just once and just treat problems differently, depending on which public method was actually called, or on the current API mode.

Which design (or combination of designs) to choose depends largely on various contextual factors:

- What are users of your API used to; what are the conventions in the target environment?
- What metaphor should the API convey? For instance, should using the API "feel" like using a "device", or like calling functions on a lightweight service module?